# Query Data from Google Spreadsheet in Android

Tags: android, google-sheets, kotlin

I am trying to query data form Google Spreadsheet available to be read by anyone with the **Read Only** link.

I implemented [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android) Quickstart solution but here is what I need:

- Access data just with URL, no authentication needed
- Query item in column A and get value in column B
- No need for updating any data

I tried constructing queries like:

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tq=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20A=C298732300456446&key=2aEqgR1CDJF5Luib-uTL0yKLuDjcTm0pOIZeCf9Sr0wAL0yK
```

But all I get is:

```
/*O_o*/
google.visualization.Query.setResponse(
{
  "version": "0.6",
  "reqId": "0",
  "status": "error",
  "errors": [
    {
      "reason": "invalid_query",
      "message": "INVALID_QUERY",
      "detailed_message": "Invalid query: NO_COLUMN: C298732300456446"
    }
  ]
}
```

This comes when the data is actually present in the sheet in column A with value `C298732300456446`.

What can I do for getting the data, without any authentication from my spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be done. If fine, I can suggest an alternative solution. You can try writing a Google App script like:

```
function doGet(e) { return getInfo(e); }
function doPost(e) { return getInfo(e); }

function getInfo(request) {

  var someValueFromUrl = request.parameter.value;
  var requiredValue = "";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet_id");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("Reading row num: " + i);

    if(data[i][0] == someValueFromUrl) {
      requiredValue = data[i][1];
      break;
    } 
  }

  Logger.log(requiredValue);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(requiredValue));
}
```

This way, you can publish this script as web app and call it using an URL which will be obtained when you publish this script.

Call the script like:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/obtained_url/exec?value=1234
```

If key is found, you will get the String response as:

```
"value"
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

C298732300456446 needs to be put within single quotes.

So you need to enclose  `C298732300456446`  as `%27C298732300456446%27`

Your'e modified query would be

`http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tq=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20A=%27C298732300456446%27&key=2aEqgR1CDJF5Luib-uTL0yKLuDjcTm0pOIZeCf9Sr0wAL0yK`

I'm unable to test this though - looks like you've removed/removed access from this spreadsheet.